# migrated azure mobile service to app service (node.js) debug locally

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

is there a way to debug azure app service (after migrating from azure mobile services) with node.js backend locally on MAC. i heard that one of the benefits for migration is the ability to debug locally. I looked in the documentation there's no clear tutorial on how to achieve that (specially there's a connection to the sql database that is maps the tables to the api calls.
i found the link below but i got confused how it will handle database sql server connections etc..

[build and deploy a node.js api app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-api-nodejs-api-app/)

Answer (score 0):

According to the article [`Advanced Debugging`](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/wiki/Advanced-Debugging) of the wiki for Node.js Tools for Visual Studio (NTVS), you can remote debugging of Node.js processes hosted on Windows Azure via Visual Studio with NTVS.

Althought Visual Studio has been not supported on MAC by now, you can try to use Visual Studio Online service to debug, please see the video [Debugging node.js](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-Online-Monaco/Debugging-nodejs) on Channel 9.

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.